# When restoring a database backup, I get this error on sql statement Incorrect syntax near @db and Incorrect syntax near Immediate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I must be so tired I cant see the problem with this statement.  I am trying to restore a db file from a backup.  con is already open.

```
 if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        string db = con.Database.ToString();
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE @db SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db",  db);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a database name variable to an alter statement. You have to build your query dynamically then executing it.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [" + db + "] SET Single_User WITH Rollback Immediate", con))
```

*But note that this way of creating sql command can risk a aql injection*